# How to create a table with pivot results using SELECT * INTO ( PIVOT Result query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table based on the results of Pivot
I am using the Select * into newTempPivot but I am getting the following error

> Must specify table to select from.
> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 118
> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

```sql
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @queryt  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @queryt =' select * into newTempPivot (SELECT date, ' + @cols1 + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols1 + ')
            ) p )'


execute(@queryt)

drop table temp
```

Please help me how can create a table with pivot results

Comment: `PRINT @queryt`/`SELECT @queryt` is your friend. But this is just a typographical error. YOu're missing a `FROM` after `newTempPivot` and an alias for your sub query. Alternatively, your second `SELECT` is in the wrong place, and it shouldn't be a subquery.

Comment: Larnu, I want a new Table to be created using the pivot results. therefore I am using select * into newTempPivot  (query result of pivot)

Comment: Your `select * into newTempPivot` is actual being interpreted as a separate statement. As @Larnu said, you need to add `FROM` after your `into newTempPivot` and have an alias defined after your last `)`

Comment: It's not `SELECT * INTO {New Table} ({Sub query})` it's `SELECT {Columns} INTO {NewTable} FROM ...`. Again `PRINT @queryt/SELECT @queryt` is your friend. Your outer query is missing a `FROM`.